# WebdriverIO - XPath not working for Chrome but for Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, firefox, xpath, webdriver-io

Following XPath works for FireFox but not for Chrome:

```
.//*/div[@class="overlay active"]/a[@class="btnAction"]
```

> Failed: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters (".//*/div[@class="overlay active"]/a[@class="btnAction").

I'm using the WebdriverIO for NodeJS and selenium-standalone server.
And using the chrome developer tools it is also possible to find the element:
[Chrome Dev Tools Match 1/1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28TH9.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide the html snippet if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually typing selector or xpath, find it from browser.

Right Click the element -> Inspect. Make sure the element is selected in your elements tab. Right click the element -> Copy -> Copy Selector/Copy Xpath. And check your selector or xpath.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but still i wonder why it didn't work with the other xPath